# Slim frameworks syntax error status 200

Tags: php, slim

Hi I am using Slim framework and would like that when a method that has some syntax error instead of returning a 200 run tate return a 500 error , but can not.

Comment: Your question is a little hard to understand, but perhaps make use of [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)?

Comment: Did you read the official documentation?